How to query and select all fields from multiple tables with the same field names prioritize earlier declared tables?
Suppose I have 2 tables. Both tables have some columns that are the same name.
Table A:



A_id
B_id
type




1
1
A



Table B:



B_id
type
value




1
B
x



I would like to craft a query such that I can select all columns  (without specifying individual tables and columns in the SELECT part) in Table A while joining Table B and also select all columns in B that do not have the same name in Table A.
The above data is to be joined on TableA.B_id = TableB.B_id.
Expected result:



A_id
B_id
type
value




1
1
A
x



I have read all of these links. They do not help solving this problem.
query multiple tables that use the same fields
match against mysql query against multiple tables with the same fields
In join query to table field have same name means how get the two fields value?
Get all value from multiple form with same field name without formset
Select from all tables having same fields
Selecting the same field from multiple tables

Note that tables have columns, not fields.

@jarlh Edited according to your information. Thank you for the correction.

Why do you want to do this? Typing the question is less work than just typing out the columns. If you have 200+ columns, then the issue is in your design. There's no built-in way of doing it so you need to write some dynamic sql using stuff from sys.tables and sys.columns. You also don't mention how you're supposed to join these. I'd pay good money to see the real data which gives needs to this though

@siggemannen I am working on a framework where the result from query is like this pattern. So, I can write it once and every other part can call this function by just specifying the table names without specifying the fields. Also, there are only a handful of columns in each table.

Am I asking an XY problem here? anyone?

@siggemannen Added information about joining. The above data is to be joined on TableA.B_id = TableB.B_id.

I'm 99% sure this is not the way, but yeah, take all columns from sys.columns for tableB which don't exist in sys.columns of tableA, build your select and execute it

@siggemannen Thank you. I will try that solution, and I will find other ways to do it.

You can see https://dbfiddle.uk/RRnylYIF for some inspiration perhaps
